# Android Cordova App crashes with ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem with an android app. The following is the error message I get:

```
11-06 18:15:02.606: E/AndroidRuntime(2424): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.wiedemann.mobile/de.wiedemann.mobile.WIEDEMANN}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.wiedemann.mobile.WIEDEMANN" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.wiedemann.mobile-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I tried the following things:

- Delete R.java
- Clean project
- Check all dependencies under project preferences -> order and export
- Uncheck "Is Library" under Tab "Android" under Project Preferences
- Restart Eclipse
- Try another workspace

Nothing works. Anyone knows how this error comes and how I can resolve it?

The Manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="de.wiedemann.mobile" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="WIEDEMANN" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file here.. specifically the application tag in the manifest file

Comment: done @VishavjeetSingh

Comment: try android:name="WIEDEMANN"  > android:name="de.wiedemann.mobile.wiedemann" . (lower case) .where do you have wiedemann class exists in class pathes? Show screenshot of application java-files tree. I think your java-files are in another directory

Comment: Sure @trololo, here http://imgur.com/oYTN4ZN . Your solution sadly didn't work

Comment: @FrederikWitte, incorrect path of java-classes in manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename package path (in Eclipse, not in Manifest) of `WIEDEMANN.java` into `wiedemann.app`  > `de.wiedemann.mobile` (as you can see in `gen` folder correct package name). Please, change symbols to lower case. Use **F2** hot key in order to rename;)

Comment: By symbols you mean WIEDEMANN to wiedemann? Or all symbols in all classes?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Just simply rename the **android:name** in your **activity** tag to **wiedemann.app.WIEDEMANN**. After watching the screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6Zo.jpg

it came to my mind I was proposing wrong answer previously.

Or Just paste this in **manifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="16" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="de.wiedemann.mobile" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="wiedemann.app.WIEDEMANN" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: [2015-11-06 19:38:24 - WIEDEMANN] /Users/witte/Dropbox2/WIEDEMANN_App/cordova_project/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:6: Tag <activity> missing required attribute name.

Comment: I said remove name attribute from **application tag not activity tag**

Comment: I think you mistook my answer.


you can undo the changes and remove name attribute from application tag

Comment: Oh, you are right, but there was no "android:name" attribute on my application tag.

Comment: Hey, I guess your answer is also right, but I will give this one to trololo, if you don't mind. You get the upvote as well, of course.